# How to Convert an Undersink Filter System to an Above Sink System

Tags: faucet, filter

I recently moved to an apartment that has a single hole granite top sink and I'm not allowed to drill any additional holes. Is there any way for me to convert my undersink filter system into something that is above sink? The filter is similar to this:

[image]

The way I see it, I have 2 issues...

1. Getting a cold water line from under the sink to above the sink. I was wondering if there was some adapter ring that I could buy that would allow me to run a cold water line out of the single hole.
2. Getting the filter water dispenser mounted somewhere that would be stable enough to not flop around everywhere.

The faucet is also one with a hose, so I would not be able to attach anything to the output end of the faucet.

The faucet and setup looks similar to this:
[image]

Comment: Is this an RO system or something else..? Is the dispenser faucet currently mounted inside your cabinet right now? An "undersink filter system" to me means that the filter is under the sink with a dispensing faucet right next to the kitchen tap, mounted in the countertop. This is in contrast to having the actual filters mounted in the basement somewhere (still, with the dispensing faucet somewhere accessible), or a whole-house filter (where the kitchen tap itself is filtered water). Picture maybe?

Comment: @gregmac I added a picture. Yes, it is an "undersink filter system" as you have described.

Comment: Tough situation. I'm definitely not aware of any type of off-the-shelf adapter ring as you described. Because of the pull-out faucet, it's going to be even more of a tough fit with the hose looping down through the countertop as well. I'd probably look at coming out the side of the cabinets or something. If there's no backsplash, and it's not an outside wall, put a hole in the drywall to route around the counter top maybe? It's really difficult to suggest viable alternatives without knowing the full layout. You could also try negotiating with the landlord to just permanently install correctly.

Comment: First of all, don't use a saddle valve to tap the cold water line. Second, you should be able to plumb the filter in line with the cold water supply for the sink. Check the user guide for the filter, it should have instructions for connecting the filter to the faucet supply line. However, depending on the filter, you may notice decreased flow to the faucet. Here's an [article that describes a direct filter setup](http://www.purewaterproducts.com/articles/undersink-filters).

Comment: @gregmac - yeah, thought it didn't hurt to ask... I think I will have to negotiate with the landlord on this one. Thanks.